# Blue card in Germany for a gay couple married in Denmark

Tags: germany, blue-card

I got a job offer from a German company who are ready to sponsor my blue card/work permit for Germany. I am gay and I want to take my partner (husband) with me. We got married in Denmark which allows foreigners to get married. Same-sex marriage is not allowed in my country (not in the EU). Is there a chance that I can take my partner (husband) with me to Germany?

Comment: How long have you been married and/or living together?

Comment: @mkennedy We've been married since June 2017.

Comment: It will help that same sex marriage is now legal in Germany. So it's legal according to the EU country where you got married, and now it's also legal according to German law.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

A blue card allows for your spouse and relatives to accompany you.

A "spouse" always means "spouse or registered partner", which is Germany's way of saying *"It's a same sex marriage, but it doesn't have 100% the same rights as a married couple, so we don't call it marriage"*. **Registered Partnership** has existed for a while. Same sex marriage actually called a marriage and being 100% equal is a relatively new thing just passing parliament this year. Same sex marriages of other states are recognized.

> Spouse/**registered partner**:
>
> The marriage must have legal validity in Germany. Marriages by tribal law
> or other marriages with non-state recognition cannot be recognized.
> In the case of immigration of a partner of the same sex, this must be a
> „registered partnership“ in the sense of the German Civil Partnership Act
> **or a partnership that is state-recognized according to foreign law**.

I cannot think of anything better suited to that "state-recognized" partnership, than an actual marriage in another EU country. So you are good. Just approach whatever government authority issued you that blue card and ask them what form to fill for your husband to join you.

Comment: I still haven't gotten the blue card. I just got the job offer and I need to apply in my local embassy for a visa (before I get the blue card in Germany). I want to apply together with my partner so he won't wait for me to get the blue card first. I want to take him with me right away.